# IN CLAUSE using createNativeQuery

Tags: java, hibernate

How to write IN clause using createNativeQuery ?

**Example**

```
codeList = "123 ,456";
```

Then I get the `codeList` like this :

```
CODE IN (:codeList)
```

But I can't get the data. What is the  correct way to write IN clause using createNativeQuery ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**IN clause** accept a **List** not a **String** so what you should to do is to convert this String to a List like this then set the parameter

```
List<Integer> listCode = Stream.of(codeList.split("\\s*,\\s*"))
       .map(Integer::valueOf)
       .collect(toList());// this will return a list [123, 456]
query.setParameter("codeList", listCode);
```

---

#### Now about your problem

When you try to use :

```
query.setParameter("codeList", "123 ,456");
```

Your query is converted like this :

```
CODE IN ('123 ,456')
         ^________^-----------------this treated as a String not as a List
```

---

There are a solution with concatenate this parameter with the query, but I don't advice with this solution!